# Anaconda VTK install missing VTK module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, anaconda, vtk

Win 10, x64, Python 3.6.6 & Python 2.7.12 (I tried the code in both), IPython 6.1.0

So far I am only able to run VTK projects using Visual Studio in C++ but would like the ease of using an interpreted language for development. So I installed the latest VTK via the Anaconda command prompt, `conda install -c anaconda vtk`

No problems everything updated & superseded as necessary. So I tried out a trial program from the [Python examples](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Python/GeometricObjects/Cell3DDemonstration/) only to get...

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vtk'
```

I added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\pkgs\vtk-8.1.0-py36he6bbf13_201\Lib\site-packages\vtk` to my PYTHONPATH in Spyder but I still get the same error.

Any idea why IPython cant see the vtk library?

EDIT: VTK shows up as an installed library when I type `conda list` at the command line

Comment: Did you try restarting Spyder after updating PYTHONPATH?

Comment: yes same error as before

Comment: Do you have other Python installed in the same system?

Comment: I have both py2 & py3 but no other installations

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me. Make sure to use the *Anaconda Prompt*.

```
# Create a new conda environment mypy3env and install vtk.
conda create -n "mypy3env" python=3
conda activate "mypy3env"
conda install -c conda-forge vtk
# Verify that python3 from Anaconda is used!
where python
python --version
# Test if vtk installation was successful
python -c "import vtk; print(vtk.vtkVersion.GetVTKVersion())"
```

See also the comments [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html) to verify the Anaconda installation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a new environment and the vtk module works for Python version 3.6. When using a newer version of Python the vtk module cannot be loaded `Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'vtkmodules.vtkCommonCore'`(I don't know why).

```
conda create --name MyEnv python=3.6
conda activate MyEnv
pip install vtk
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30699769)